# Delete rows based on a range of string conditionals

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have dozens of spreadsheets thousands of rows long and I want to subset them by deleting rows that do not satisfy a condition.

Let me put forward a simplified example.  Say Row C has string values for department names at a university (eg "ANTHRO" is Anthropology, "ART-HIST" is Art History, and so on).  The university has many departments and the spreadsheet has many entries for each department, but I only want data for Anthropology and Art History.  Therefore my task is to write a script that deletes each row that does not satisfy the condition RowC = "ANTHRO" or "ART-HIST".

Problem is, I don't know how in javascript/google-apps-script to define a variable that takes a range of (string) values. One attempt saw me define a "cull" variable as an array containing the conditions the script will judge the data on:

```
 var rowsDeleted = 0;
  var keep = ["ANTHRO", "ART-HIST"];
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[2] != keep) {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};
```

Yet it did not work.  I know I could simply write `if(row[2] != "ANTHRO" || != "ART")`, but in reality there are much more than two conditions.  Defining the so-called "cull" variable seems more efficient.

Any insights as to why the array-approach did not work?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using indexOf. If the row value isn't inside the array, it will return a value of -1, otherwise will return the index.

```
  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  var keep = ["ANTHRO",
              "ART-HIST"];
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (keep.indexOf(row[2]) === -1) {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, what you're trying to do really is to filter a collecion of data based on speicific conditions. First you can store thousands rows of data into an array, and each element of the array can be a object to represent a row of many columns. And then you can filter the array by condition that whether a row contains string "ANTHRO" or "ART-HIST". A possible code implementaiton is:

```
var data = [
    { DEPT_ID: 1, ABBR_NAME: "ANTHRO", FULL_NAME: "Anthropology", StudentsNO: 240 },
    { DEPT_ID: 2, ABBR_NAME: "ART-HIST", NAME: "Art History", StudentsNO: 200 },
    { DEPT_ID: 3, ABBR_NAME: "MATH", FULL_NAME: "Mathematics", StudentsNO: 50 },
    { DEPT_ID: 4, ABBR_NAME: "CS", NAME: "Computer Science", StudentsNO: 79 }
];

function isAnthroOrArtHist(element) {
    return ["ANTHRO", "ART-HIST"].indexOf(element.ABBR_NAME) >= 0;
}
var newData = data.filter(isAnthroOrArtHist);
```

Answer (score 0):

I sort of do the same thing where I pull a list of Liquor Inventory to another tab along with a VENDOR name and if the VENDOR name isn't listed, then it hides the row

Here's what I used. You might be able to tweak it to where you need.

```
function liquorOrderGuideWorking() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('LIQUOR ORDER'); 
 // Rows start at "1" - this will delete the first two rows
 //sheet.deleteRows(2, 567);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var liquorInventory = ss.getSheetByName('LIQUOR INVENTORY'); 

  var liquorInventoryRange = liquorInventory.getRange('B6:C573');  //Holds Vendor & Item Name
  var liquorInventoryTotalRange = liquorInventory.getRange('I6:I573'); //Holds QTY of each item

  var liquorOrder = ss.getSheetByName('LIQUOR ORDER'); //Gets the new sheet
  var liquorOrderRange = liquorOrder.getRange('A2:B569');  //Places Vendor & Item Name
  var liquorOrderQTYRange = liquorOrder.getRange('C2:C569'); //Places QTY

  liquorInventoryRange.copyTo(liquorOrderRange, {contentsOnly:true})
  liquorInventoryTotalRange.copyTo(liquorOrderQTYRange, {contentsOnly:true})

  var s = ss.getSheetByName('LIQUOR ORDER');
  var lastCol = s.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();

  // assumes headers in row 1
  var r = s.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, lastCol);

  // Note the use of an array
  r.sort([{ column: 1, ascending: true }, { column: 2, ascending: true}]);

  var ssHide = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ssHide.getSheetByName('LIQUOR ORDER');
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  //show all the rows
  sheet.showRows(1, maxRows);

  //get data from column B
  var data = sheet.getRange('A:A').getValues();

  //iterate over all rows
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
    //compare first character, if blank, then hide row
    if(data[i][0].charAt(0) == ''){
      sheet.hideRows(i+1);
    }
  }
Browser.msgBox('Liquor Order Guide','The Liquor Order Guide has been refreshed successfully.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```